# Find regex pattern in text file and output each match to new text file

Tags: regex, bash

I have one long text file with many articles in it that I want to split to individual text files (one article = one file) so I can use them in a CMS which works with text files.

I have prepared my file in a way I can differentiate between every article by using a couple of hashtags as a divider like so:

```
----
Content: First article text
----
Slug: first-article
----

####

----
Content: Second article text
----
Slug: second-article
----

####
```

**I want to match every article via regular expression and create new text files for every match.**
How would one do that? I already figured out the regex with Sublime (`(?s)####\n\n.+?\n\n`) but how do I output the match to a new text file? I assume there must be a way with bash scripting (which I have never used before)?

Edit: Preferably each text file should be named after the article’s slug.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to name the files?

Comment: Good point. Each article includes a slug, so I guess that would be helpful. I will edit my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="####" # set record separator to ####
           } 
           { 
             slug=""; # initialise a variable for later
             match($0,/Slug:.*[[:space:]]/); # Match for the slurp text
             slug=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-8); Extract the slup text after ":"
             if (slug!="") { 
                      print $0 > slug # If slug is set, print the line to a file named by contents of slug 
             }  
            }' file
```

One liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="####" } { slug="";match($0,/Slug:.*[[:space:]]/);slug=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-8);if (slug!="") { print $0 > slug }  }'
```

Comment: Might want to throw a `close(slug)` in there to keep things tidy.